# I wanted to outer join both the below tables

Tags: r

[image]

[image]

This is my code :

```
X = read.csv("cpm-gender.csv")
Y = read.csv("page-level-gender.csv")
Z = merge(Y,X,by = c("Gender"),all = TRUE)


Z = merge(X,Y,by = c("Gender","Average_Age"),all = TRUE)
```

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column

```
Z = merge(X,Y,by = "Gender",all = TRUE)
```

> Error in merge.data.frame(X, Y, by = "Gender", all = TRUE) : 
>     negative length vectors are not allowed.

Please someone give me a solution join both to perform machine learning on the combined data .

Comment: You're trying to join by a column that isn't in your tables - `"Average_All"` is not present.

Comment: It is Average_AGE and if you see both tables. It is present in both

Comment: The column you should be joining on is `Average.Age`, not underscored

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be trying to merge on the wrong column name. Try:

```
Z = merge(X,Y,by = c("Gender","Average.Age"),all = TRUE)
```

or

```
Z = merge(X,Y, by = "Average.Age", all = TRUE)
```